# Integrity constraint violation when attempting to create salesrule

Tags: magento-1.7, shopping-cart-price-rules

I've been trying to programmatically create a salesrule that applies a fixed discount if the given conditions are met:

- The customer email is `emailtest@test.com`
- The `skuvisible` (custom product attribute in our Magento) is `46306`

For that, I came up with this code:

```
$conditions['conditions']['1'] = array(
    'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_combine',
    'aggregator' => 'all',
    'value' => '1',
    'new_child' => ''
);
$conditions['conditions']['1--1'] = array(
    'type' => 'amrules/rule_condition_customer',
    'attribute' => 'email',
    'operator' => '==',
    'value' => 'emailtest@test.com'
);
$conditions['conditions']['1--2'] = array(
    'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_product_found',
    'aggregator' => 'all',
    'value' => '1',
    'new_child' => ''
);
$conditions['conditions']['1--2--1'] = array(
    'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_product',
    'attribute' => 'skuvisible',
    'operator' => '==',
    'value' => '46306'
);

$model = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule');

$data = array(
    'name' => "rule-name",
    'description' => "rule-name",
    'is_active' => '1',
    'website_ids' => array(126),
    'coupon_type' => Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::COUPON_TYPE_SPECIFIC,
    'uses_per_customer' => 1,
    'from_date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-3 hours')),
    'to_date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-3 hours')),
    'is_rss' => '0',
    'simple_action' => Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::CART_FIXED_ACTION,
    'discount_amount' => 455,
    'discount_qty' => 0,
    'stop_rules_processing' => '1',
    'store_labels' => array(0 => "AllwaysOn-Other"),
    'salesrule_type' => 'default',
    'conditions' => $conditions['conditions']
);

$model->loadPost($data);
$model->save();
```

However, when I run it, I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`clara`.`salesrule_product_attribute`, CONSTRAINT `FK_SALESRULE_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_RULE_ID_SALESRULE_RULE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`rule_id`) REFERENCES `salesrule` (`rule_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPD)INSERT INTO `salesrule_product_attribute` () VALUES () Array
(
)


Trace:
#0 /home/morgan/soft-liness-2.glamit_magento1/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/morgan/soft-liness-2.glamit_magento1/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/morgan/soft-liness-2.glamit_magento1/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/morgan/soft-liness-2.glamit_magento1/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#4 /home/morgan/soft-liness-2.glamit_magento1/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#5 /home/morgan/soft-liness-2.glamit_magento1/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(574): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#6 /home/morgan/soft-liness-2.glamit_magento1/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(1929): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('salesrule_produ...', Array)
#7 /home/morgan/soft-liness-2.glamit_magento1/app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Resource/Rule.php(293): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->insertMultiple('salesrule_produ...', Array)
#8 /home/morgan/soft-liness-2.glamit_magento1/app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Resource/Rule.php(133): Mage_SalesRule_Model_Resource_Rule->setActualProductAttributes(Object(Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule), Array)
#9 /home/morgan/soft-liness-2.glamit_magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(544): Mage_SalesRule_Model_Resource_Rule->_afterSave(Object(Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule))
#10 /home/morgan/soft-liness-2.glamit_magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule))
#11 /home/morgan/soft-liness-2.glamit_magento1/app/code/local/Ropit/Prueba/controllers/PruebaController.php(55): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#12 /home/morgan/soft-liness-2.glamit_magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Ropit_Prueba_PruebaController->testcoupAction()
#13 /home/morgan/soft-liness-2.glamit_magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('testcoup')
#14 /home/morgan/soft-liness-2.glamit_magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#15 /home/morgan/soft-liness-2.glamit_magento1/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#16 /home/morgan/soft-liness-2.glamit_magento1/app/Mage.php(691): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#17 /home/morgan/soft-liness-2.glamit_magento1/index.php(112): Mage::run('clara', 'website')
#18 {main}
```

I don't get why this happens, because when I try to create the same rule using the admin panel with the same conditions, the error doesn't appear.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out!
Turns out certain salesrule conditions require you to provide a `customer_group_ids`, otherwise Magento will attempt to perform an empty insert on `salesrule_product_attribute` table.

Therefore, the working code is as follows:

```
$customer_group = new Mage_Customer_Model_Group();
$allGroups = $customer_group->getCollection()->toOptionHash();
$groups = array();
foreach ($allGroups as $key => $value) {
    $groups[] = $key;
}

$conditions['conditions']['1'] = array(
    'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_combine',
    'aggregator' => 'all',
    'value' => '1',
    'new_child' => ''
);
$conditions['conditions']['1--1'] = array(
    'type' => 'amrules/rule_condition_customer',
    'attribute' => 'email',
    'operator' => '==',
    'value' => 'emailtest@test.com'
);
$conditions['conditions']['1--2'] = array(
    'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_product_found',
    'aggregator' => 'all',
    'value' => '1',
    'new_child' => ''
);
$conditions['conditions']['1--2--1'] = array(
    'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_product',
    'attribute' => 'skuvisible',
    'operator' => '==',
    'value' => '46306'
);

$model = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule');

$data = array(
    'name' => "rule-name",
    'description' => "rule-name",
    'is_active' => '1',
    'website_ids' => array(126),
    'coupon_type' => Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::COUPON_TYPE_SPECIFIC,
    'uses_per_customer' => 1,
    'from_date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-3 hours')),
    'to_date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-3 hours')),
    'is_rss' => '0',
    'simple_action' => Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::CART_FIXED_ACTION,
    'discount_amount' => 455,
    'discount_qty' => 0,
    'stop_rules_processing' => '1',
    'store_labels' => array(0 => "AllwaysOn-Other"),
    'salesrule_type' => 'default',
    'customer_group_ids' => $groups,
    'conditions' => $conditions['conditions']
);

$model->loadPost($data);
$model->save();
```